# how to highlight centroid of a radius area when zooming to extent of radii

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, zoom

I am trying to figure out a way to highlight the centroid of a radius after right clicking on the radii attribute and zooming to its extent.  ultimately, I want to batch export a few hundred maps with each map showing the highlighted centroid at a 5 mile extent.
Another thought I have (if its possible) is to set the 'zoom to selected feature' extent to 5 miles for the points shpfile.  Then I can discard the radius shpfile and work soley with the points.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What version of arcMap are you using? And type: Desktop or AGOL?

Comment: Desktop Basic (aka ArcView) but also have access to Desktop Standard (aka ArcEditor)

Comment: both the basic and standard are 10.3.1

Comment: Have a look at data driven pages

Answer (score 1):

Use data driven pages and set your centroids as the index layer. Then, use a page definition to show only the centroid that is active on the page. See this help doc... http://support.esri.com/cN/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/41354